# Can we have same columns for Indexing and primary key - Informix DB

Tags: sql, indexing, primary-key, informix

Is possible to add an Indexing columns in a table that already have a primary key - Informix DB?

I have done inserted the indexing, then i drop it, it shown errors" Index does not exist" - DROP Index..

Then I created three columns Indexing that also set as primary key, 
when I created , its shown errors "Index already exists on column."
- create index ...

Comment: Informix supports `create index`, so yes, you can add indexes to an existing table.

Comment: create index (column_a, Column_b, column_c) , and this columns (column_a, Column_b, column_c) also primary key... does this what you means.

Comment: Looks like it's fully supported; https://razorsql.com/docs/informix_create_index.html

Comment: When you specify a primary key constraint in a CREATE TABLE statement, the Informix server creates an appropriate unique index on the columns automatically.  If you want to do something more fancy with the index, create the table without the primary key constraint, create the unique index in a separate CREATE INDEX statement, and then alter the table to add the primary key constraint.  The server should use the existing index for the primary key constraint too.